# Why is -1 / 2 == -1 in Ruby and Python?

Tags: python, ruby, integer-division

`1/2` is actually `0` as expected in both languages since it's integer division.

One would expect the result to be 0 for `-1/2` too. But it's `-1`!
In other languages like Java, Scala or C++ it's `0` as it should be.
What happens in Ruby and Python and why?

Comment: Related: `-1 % 2`.

Comment: Note that `/` is **not** integer division in Python 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is to preserve the identity that `(x / y) * y + (x % y) == x` for all integers `x` and `y != 0`; this is what it means for `x % y` to be the remainder when `x` is divided by `y`.

In Java, integer division rounds towards zero, but this means the remainder operator `%` can give negative results, and this is inconvenient for most purposes. For example, the expression `arr[i % arr.length]` doesn't guarantee a valid array index when `i` is negative.

In Python, if `y` is positive then `x % y` always gives a non-negative result (in the range from `0` to `y - 1` inclusive), so to preserve the "remainder" property, integer division has to always round down, not necessarily towards zero.

Comment: This is only true when using integer division, which in Python is accomplished with the `//` operator.  In Python 2, `/` when used with two integer operands also performs integer division, but that usage is deprecated, and in Python 3 `/` uses floating point division when given two integers.

Comment: @TomKarzes Yes, the question is about integer division.

Answer (score 2):

When doing integer math, it basically does a floor operation, or rounds down.
So:

```
1/2 == 0.5 # rounds down to 0
```

But

```
-1/2 == -0.5 # which rounds down to -1
```

If you want the result to equal 0 you can run the following:

```
int(-1/2)
```